# Deploying multi-tenant on Amazon RDS (individual DB for each tenant)

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, amazon-rds

I am currently conceptualizing a cloud application (SaaS) and I am looking to create a DB for every user (tenant) that is registering an account.

May I know if it is programmatically possible to create a new DB on Amazon RDS through API or anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databases are created on RDS using standard SQL DDL statements -- not the API.

For example:

> To create additional databases, connect to the DB instance and use the SQL command `CREATE DATABASE`.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateInstance.html

Comment: I was thinking too much initially and forgot the simplest stuff. :/

Thanks for your answer!